# Nice interpretation of "be in a position to"?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-meaning

Having googled the phrase "be in a position to" and examined its usage, I temporarily conclude that "be in a position to" is equivalent to "can if willing to".

But I am not quite sure if my interpretation is proper. If not, I would like to know a nicer interpretation so that I can more appropriately manipulate it.

Comment: A better interpretation is "be able to"

Comment: Ah thanks. So "can" may in some sense also fit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'be in a position to' speaks about your ***'position'***. Now this could be anything... your capability, strength, financial status, busyness or the like.

The best example I can think of is when you are holding an ice cream cup in each of your hands, and then someone calls on your cellphone which is in your pocket. You are `not in a position` to pick the call.

Comment: Another, non-literal example: Your final exam schedule is planned by the school's registrar, but you lament to your professor about the inconvenient scheduling. Although sympathetic, your professor is *not in a position* to change the exam schedule.

Comment: @OperaticSkeleton true! ;)

Comment: Many thanks; I see! Such an expression provides me with the ability to characterize a state more precisely! Indeed, sometimes I knew that "can" is not precise enough to describe what I want to say but I did not have an alternative option. Now, with "be in a position to", I am in a position to more vividly express what I want to express.

Comment: @Chou ah, that way. You can certainly use 'not in a position' rather than 'cannot' to sound polite! :)